# Meteor event selector for a given attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

This Meteor template event needs to fire only in the `input` element which has the attribute `name=abc`, Is there a way to do this?

```js
'keyup input[name-attribute is abc??]': function (evt, template) {

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than you guessed:

```
'keyup input[name=abc]': function (evt, template) {

};
```